# Missing classes defined in window when eval in Sandbox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, sandbox, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a problem trying to evaluate some source code in Sandbox. I added some classes to the window (DOM) object and I really need these classes to be included in Sandbox. Eg:

```
window.BaseClass = function(){this.someProperty = "bla bla";}

...

var ctx = new Components.utils.Sandbox(window);
    ctx.BaseClass = BaseClass; //This is neccesary

var src = "function SubClass(){}; SubClass.prototype = new BaseClass();";

var evaluation = Components.utils.evalInSandbox(src, ctx);
var res = new evaluation[className];

alert(res);
```

The problem is these new classes are not always the same, so I can't just to `ctx.BaseClass = BaseClass;` all the time. So is there a way to include in SandBox all the classes window has defined?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on your question/goal (elaborate please, and provide a complete, standalone, re-producible example), but a good start would be to use [`sandboxPrototype: window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.Sandbox#Sandbox_options) and maybe turn `wantXrays` off (beware: security implications!)

Comment: Hi! It is a complete example. The problem is Sandbox recreate a context with all window properties but BaseClass. So, I have to por it explicitly this way: ctx.BaseClass = BaseClass; But I really need to avoid doing this, because cometimes I don't know all the classes

Comment: There is no clear examples about how to use the sandbox options. EG:

Comment: new Components.utils.Sandbox(win[wantXrays])
new Components.utils.Sandbox(win[{wantXrays:tre}])

Comment: xrays is not useful. I found the way to define it but didn't work:

var sandbox = new Components.utils.Sandbox(
 aContentWin,
 {
 'sandboxName': aScript.id,
 'sandboxPrototype': aContentWin,
 'wantXrays': true,
 });

Comment: The example is not complete and reproducible. I cannot put it in a file/scratchpad/whatever (you didn't tell how it should be run, nor is the code complete) and then run it to reproduce your problem using the steps you have provided in your question (you didn't provide steps). Regarding `wantXRays`, you'll want them *off*, i.e `wantXRays: false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to get the new class from the evalInSandbox result. That was the problem: I had to do it from the context:

```
Components.utils.evalInSandbox(src, ctx);
var res = new ctx[className];
```